# Open source project order editing is broken on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, open-source

The order of Open Source Projects on my careers page doesn't always auto-save. After a refresh the items go back to where they were before I moved them.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it has been fixed.  Please let me know if it is still not working for you.